# Connect to MongoDB with TLS enabled using an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssl, pymongo, ssh-tunnel, aws-documentdb

I have a amazon DocumentDB cluster in a different region, in private VPC, that I can access from a bastion where I can connect using SSH.

I am tunnelling the database server to my local machine and connnecting using pymongo.

```py
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pymongo, json

def format_db_uri(user,password,host,port,**kwargs):
    h1 = f'mongodb://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/?' 
    options = '&'.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items())
    print(options)
    return h1 + options

def connect_mongo_via_bastion(config):
    ssh_config = dict(config['bastion'])
    mongo_config = dict(config['mongo'])
    
    server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        **ssh_config,
        remote_bind_address=(
            mongo_config['host'], 
            mongo_config['port']
        )
    )
    server.start()
    
    # override the server address
    mongo_config['host'], mongo_config['port'] = server.local_bind_address
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(format_db_uri(**mongo_config)) 
    return client, server
```

And I use like this

```py
client, bastion = connect_mongo_via_bastion(my_config)
client.list_databases()
```

And it fails with

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 0.0.0.0:53374: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '0.0.0.0'. (_ssl.c:997), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: ]>
```

How can I connect in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sslAllowInvalidHostnames` to the mongodb uri. In your script add something like `mongo_config['sslAllowInvalidHostnames'] = True`